# Why laravel queue attempting same job multiple time if email address is valid?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have to send mail through laravel application, first I used simple laravel Mail function, but it was taking lot of time when I was sending 10-15 emails, So I implement Queue. Also put command  - php artisan queue:work -  on server.

Issue is sometime it executes all job properly and sometime all jobs will fail, even if I have added correct To-email address.
Also why its trying single job multiple time? why its not sending mail same time when first time it executing job?

This is how I am calling dispacher in my controller.

```
 foreach($userList as $user){
            dispatch(new queueMail($data));
 }
```

Comment: Check your log files for any errors and post it here.

Comment: Log file showing error after attempt reaches to 255  - local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'attempts' at row 1 (SQL: update `jobs` set `reserved_at` = 1564313996, `attempts` = 256 where `id` = 2284)

Answer (score 0):

Same thought here, so far, I think it's due to OS issue that the OS terminates the job worker because of the CPU or RAM shortage. For me, such situation usaully observed at a small CPU and RAM machine.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33403759)